# How to save the session identifier and send it when accessing the server?

Tags: android, retrofit2

To maintain a session, I have to use a session id. 
How to save a session identifier and send it every time you access the server?

- I get the session identifier in **header**. Here is the response from the server from Fiddler:

Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=b09aa2c816d1b;

- **Class for generating an interface:**

  ```
  public class NetworkService {
  private static final String BASE_URL = "http://";
  private static NetworkService mInstance;
  private Retrofit mRetrofit;

  private NetworkService() {
      mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
              .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
              .build();
  }
  public static NetworkService getInstance() {
      if (mInstance == null) {
          mInstance = new NetworkService();
      }
      return mInstance;
  }
  public ApiInterface service() {
      return mRetrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
  }
  }
  ```
- **Api:**

  ```
  public interface ApiInterface {
  @POST("Register?app=WebAPI")
  Call<RegResponse> registration(@Query("phone") String phone);
  }
  ```
- **USE:**

  ```
  NetworkService.getInstance()
  .service()
  .registration(phone)                
  .enqueue(new Callback<RegResponse>() {
  @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<RegResponse> call, Response<RegResponse>response) {

      }
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<RegResponse> call, Throwable t) {
  }
  });
  ```

Can someone please help me to solve this issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save session id in local device use Shared Preferences, Here  is shared pref e.g to save & retrieve session id.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SharedPrefManager {

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;


    public SharedPrefManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void savesession(String sessionid){
        editor.putString("SESSION_ID",session);
        editor.commit();
    }

   public String getsessionid(){
          String sessionid = pref.getString("SESSION_ID", null);
          return sessionid;
   }


}
```

**Usage**

```java
//To save Sessionid from onResponse method
...
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RegResponse> call, Response<RegResponse>response) {
          // Get sessionid from response object.

          ...
          SharedPrefManager manager = new SharedPrefManager(getApplicationContext());
           //Context object is require to create its object.

          ...
         manager.savesessionid(sessionid);//sessionid is string object got from response above

    }
  ....
```

```java
// When you want to send sessionid to server either in request data or in request header, get sessionid string object from SharedPrefManager and append it to request object.


SharedPrefManager manager = new SharedPrefManager(getApplicationContext());

String sessionid = manager.getsessionid();
```

Comment: Yes thank you ! Good way. Tell me how to get the session identifier from a cookie. This way I get the string: JSESSIONID=asdasddfsdf234234; 
but only an identifier is needed without JSESSIONID ?

Comment: if you are getting string using ```response.headers().get("Set-Cookie")```  then you can get identifier without JSESSIONID by splitting this string like this.
```java String str =  response.headers().get("Set-Cookie");
     String arr[] = str.split("=");
    String identifier = arr[1];
```

Comment: Is there something wrong. I get this value: ba13451c4576b69ebc2cbea746df5bf; Path

Comment: No there is nothing wrong if you are getting semicolon (;) along with identifier then you can remove it like this.
```identifier = identifier.substring(0, identifier.length()-1);``` this way you will have only ba13451c4576b69ebc2cbea746df5bf

Comment: ba13451c4576b69ebc2cbea746df5bf; Path - the word "path" is also saved

Comment: There was nothing like path in ```Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=b09aa2c816d1b;``` can you print & see identifier before save. I think path should not be with this.